# Pass errorlevel for a PowerShell cmdlet to a batch file

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I am modifying an existing batch file to test a port on a server. The only way I can see to do this is with PowerShell. I need to execute a cmdlet and pass the errorlevel back to the batch file. So I execute something like this:

```
PowerShell -Command "Test-NetConnection -ComputerName www.google.com -Port 80"
```

- This is an existing *approved* script, and I'm only making this one change, not rewriting the entire thing into PowerShell
- Since this is a cmdlet, $? passes the error as True or False, not $LastExitCode

Comment: so ... you can set `$LastExitCode` & you can use the error codes in PoSh to decide what exit code to use. [*grin*]

Comment: Example, please?

Comment: set the $Var thus >>> `$LASTEXITCODE = '666'` <<< and then send it out by emitting the $Var. ///// actually, there is no need to use `$LASTEXITCODE` ... you can just emit whatever value you want. ///// you can also create a flag file or error text file that your BAT file can read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `Test-Connection`, `Test-NetConnection` do not throw directly an error, only a warning when connection fails (but you cannot test a port with the first one). Exactly, an error cannot be found with ErrorVariable, but this not throw with ErrorAction.

I think the best should this :

```
@echo off
PowerShell -Command "try { Test-NetConnection -ComputerName localhost -Port 80 -WarningAction Stop } catch { exit 1 }"
if ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error
echo Continue
exit
:error
echo Error
```

`ERRORLEVEL` will be 0 if connection is validated and 1 if connection failed (you can of course set the exit code you want).

Comment: Now I'm really befuddled. It works perfectly on my home computer but not my work computer.  %ERRORLEVEL% never gets defined.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help.